# BubbleSort using vectors returning garbage or 0s

Tags: c++, sorting, parameter-passing

I've been practicing passing by value and passing by reference then I tried a BubbleSort using vectors and realized i have to pass the paramter of the function by reference , But when I do that the displayed list is either 0s when i dont pass by reference or when i do , It's just garbage number
Have i understood the passing by value/reference wrong ? 
Here's the sorting function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void BubbleSort(vector<int>&list){
    int temp;
    for (int unsigned i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        for (int unsigned j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){
            if(list[i]>list[j]){
                temp=list[i];
                list[i]=list[j];
                list[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void display(vector<int>list){
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        cout << list[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

And here's the main one:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int k;
    int x,a;
    vector<int>list;
    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you want to enlist \n";
    cin >> k;
    cout << "Enter the numbers of your list \n";
    while((list.size()< k) && (cin >> x)){
        list.push_back(a);
    }
    BubbleSort(list);
    display(list);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` is always "garbage", when adding.

Comment: @user2864740 But why's that ?

Comment: @Oliver when do you ever set `a` to any value?

Comment: Because you never set it to an initial value. Trying to read it will give undefined behavior.

Comment: More specifically, you `(cin >> x)` but `push_back(a)`.

Comment: Oh that's true thanks everyone , I thought i had to declare another variable for the list itself , Good point

Answer (score 2):

You’re pushing the wrong value onto the list, try this instead

```
 list.push_back(x);
```

Comment: Make sure you change `cin >> x` to `cin >> a` before you do this, though ;)

Comment: Yes thank you , I realize that now.